# Is it possible to prevent SQL Agent Job from running if related job or previous instance has not finished?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have three SQL Agent jobs, one for each of three registries being managed. These go off on a staggered schedule every two hours (i.e. Reg 1 at 9am, 3pm; Reg 2 at 11am, 5pm; Reg 3 at 1pm, 7pm).

In most every circumstance, it takes less than two hours for one of these jobs to run. However, if it is taking longer than expected, I do NOT want the other job to run. So, if Reg 1's 9am run is taking more than 2 hours, I do not want Reg 2's 11am job to run UNTIL Reg 1's job is completed.

How can I work this conditional run functionality in? I am not seeing anything in the schedules properties of the job. Let me know if you need more clarification!

Thanks!!

Comment: You could write a final step into each job that writes a row to a table in a DBA database when it completes. Then, have the next job verify that confirmation row exists before it fires up.  It probably wouldn't hurt to log information about job completion anyway.

Comment: why not just trigger job Reg2 as last step of Reg1? otherwise you will be pretty stuck, job-scheduling in ms-sql is quite primitive.
example-sql for the last sql-task: "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Reg2';"